# Doctrine - Generate entities from database Views

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to generate entites with Doctrine from existing DB.

Doctrine generates correctly entities 'stored' at Tables but not generates entities from Database **Views**.

I will try to mapping them manually but I would like to know if is there any alternative option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine does not currently support generating Entites from Views. You can however manually map them like you seem to be doing.

Just be sure to use the readOnly option of the @Entity annotation.

This is because a View is technically not a Table. It's a pseudo-table that is the result of a Query.

In the future Doctrine might support Views, but as it stands and where things are going I suspect it won't, using Views should be, where possible, avoided. They offer bad performance and add to the schema complexity of your database.